# How do you remove a user role via a hook update?

Tags: users, hooks

I would like to remove a user role via a hook update in Drupal 9.

I believe I would need to do something like the below but unclear what other code might be needed.

```
$user->removeRole('administrator');
$user->save();
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove a role from a specific user? Or delete the role so that it no longer exists in the system and can't be assigned to any user?

Comment: First remove the role for all users who have the assigned role. Then delete the role so that it no longer exists in the system and can't be assigned to any user.

Comment: Search for drupal batch process update hook. Because when you want to process a lot of users you may want to prevent timeouts when your update hook runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, load all your users having the role you wish to delete:

```
$usersHavingRole = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadByProperties(['roles' => 'my_role']);
```

Then, for each user, remove the role (this is the code you mentioned):

```
foreach($usersHavingRole as $user) {
  $user->removeRole('my_role');
  $user->save();
}
```

And finally, delete the role:

```
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::load('my_role');
if (!empty($role)) {
  $role->delete();
}
```

Comment: I guess OP is more in search of actual update hook code implementing a batch process at best.